# What is the antonym of "distaff"?

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonym of "distaff"?  It's not in my dictionary, but it must exist.  Right?

**edit** By *distaff* I mean, "the female equivalent of something typically male", not just "female" generally.  I could write "Joan Jett is the distaff Adam Ant" or "Adam Ant is the [what?] Joan Jett".

**further edit** no cracks about my musical ignorance.

Comment: If by *distaff*, you mean *female*, then the answer is *male*. If you have another meaning, you should say what you think it should mean.

Comment: @tchrist -- edited.

Comment: It's not in my dictionary, but it must exist. Right? ... A very dodgy premise. Look up 'lacuna'; 'semantic gap'.

Comment: "Dat staff", obviously!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is really just General Reference, but from Merriam-Webster...

> [**sword side**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sword%20side) noun
>    *the father's side of a family — compare **distaff***
>
> [**spear side**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spear?show=0&t=1375065375) noun
>   : *paternal; the spear side of the family — compare **distaff***
>
> [**distaff**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distaff) noun
>   **1 a** : *a staff for holding the flax, tow, or wool in spinning; **b** : woman's work or domain*
>   **2** : *the female branch or side of a family*

I suppose *Joan Jett is the **distaff** Adam Ant* means the ***female equivalent of***, but although it's perfectly comprehensible, it's not at all a standard usage. If OP is happy with non-standard usages, he might as well go for *Adam Ant is the [**puppy dog tail**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Are_Little_Boys_Made_Of?) Joan Jet*. Otherwise, ***male equivalent***.

EDIT: I'm slightly ashamed to admit I'd never heard of Joan Jett until I came back to this answer the following day. Now somewhat wiser, I have to say that OP's usage looks *exceptionally* unlikely (she couldn't be further from the normal associations of *distaff!* :). Maybe a better way to say it...

> *Adam Ant is the **warlock** to Joan Jet's **witch***

Comment: *Slightly* ashamed?  She founded [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runaways) important [rock bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joan_Jett#Joan_Jett_and_the_Blackhearts), she's been [in movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_of_Day) and she's had movies [made about her](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runaways_%28film%29).  What does a girl have to do?

Comment: @Malvolio: Bite the head off a live chicken on stage, like [Alice Cooper?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Cooper) Die young, like Jimi Hendrix, Janis Joplin, Amy Winehouse? I've only got sufficient "brain-based" memory storage for one MOR female rock singer into vegetarianism, and that slot is already occupied by [Chrissie Hynde of The Pretenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrissie_Hynde) (whose music I like much better than what I've just heard from Joan Jett on Spotify! :).

Comment: yes, if you have only one slot, use it for Chrissie, or P!nk, or Amy Lee.  If you have *four* slots (and maybe you should) then Jett too.  But [dying young](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/27_Club) is for wankers, and neither Cooper nor Ozzy Osbourne ever bit the head off a chicken.

Comment: @Malvolio: I know neither of them *really* did it - but the possibility that they *might have* would have been enough to make me notice them. Anyway, Ozzy still keeps turning up on UK daytime TV, and (again, I'm slightly ashamed to admit) I can still remember watching Alice Cooper perform *School's Out* on *Top of the Pops* (sigh - those were the daze! :)

Comment: "…it's not at all a standard usage."  This is in fact the *only* sense in which I've ever seen the word used.

Comment: @Atario: The *sense* of OP's example is indeed "standard", but not the *syntax*. I can only see the full usage in context for a single instance of [*she is the distaff (some "male equivalent" noun)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+is+the+distaff%22) in Google Books. A far more normal usage, with a claimed 816 written instances, is [*she is the female equivalent (of some male exemplar)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+is+the+female+equivalent%22). I still think OP's exact example usage is dated/quirky/unusual.

Comment: I see what you mean; however, even so, I've only ever seen it in this syntax too, though usually not for a specific person.  "My play is a distaff _Twelve Angry Men_." and the like.

Comment: @Atario: I'm surprised at that. Use of the actual word ***distaff*** has [declined massively over the past couple of centuries](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%5Bthe+distaff%5D-%5Bthe+distaff+side%5D%2Cthe+distaff+side&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%5Bthe%20distaff%5D%20-%20%5Bthe%20distaff%20side%5D%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20distaff%20side%3B%2Cc0), but for the past 70-odd years, almost half of all usages are *the distaff **side** (of the family)*. To me, it's now primarily just a "fixed phrase" antiquarian / genealogical usage.

Comment: In case you need further education on her, Jett co-authored one of the best power/punk songs ever: "I Hate Myself For Loving You."

Answer (score 7):

*Distaff*, in this context, is defined as "the female branch of the family":

> **[distaff](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distaff)**
>
> noun
>
> 1a stick or spindle on to which wool or flax is wound for spinning.
>
> 2 [as modifier] of or concerning women:
>
> marriage is still the passport to distaff power
>
> Phrases
>
> *the distaff side*
>
> the female side of a family:
>
> *the family title could be passed down through the **distaff** side*

As stated in the full definition, the term for the male branch of the family is *spear*.

The dictionary definition for *[spear](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spear?q=spear)* refers to "the *spear* side", but doesn't mention *spear* as meaning 'of or concerning men'.

I guess you could say that when talking about family trees, the antonym of *distaff* is *spear*, but outside of that context, there isn't an antonym.

Answer (score 2):

While they call upon different linguistic roots, and have a focus that is somewhat genital (as does spear), there are several male-female pairs, such as

> [yang](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yang?view=uk) (male) as compared to yin (female)
>
> and
>
> [lingam](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lingam?q=lingam) (male) in contrast/complement to yoni (female)

The comparison could be rendered *"Adam Ant is the yang [or lingam] version of Joan Jett".*

A punchier approach would be *"Adam Ant is the yang [or lingam] Joan Jett".*

Answer (score 2):

My immediate thought was "staff" as I have definitely heard my father use it as the opposite of "distaff".  Searching the internet for a dictionary definition relating to this use has so far proved fruitless.

It does appear that "sword side" and "spear side" are rather old antonyms of "distaff side", but there are some [books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CdX2dVP0iTMC&pg=PT138&lpg=PT138&dq=%22staff%20and%20distaff%22&source=bl&ots=5mbjTNueOz&sig=y-hXXprGZBkm5AFttYNUiKHh7Ng&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aDr2UZSFHsSP0AXWoYCYAg&ved=0CGMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22staff%20and%20distaff%22&f=false), [web sites](http://www.warhorseplace.com/index.cfm/stallions/midas-touch-gb/midas-touch-gb-nicks/) and [publications](http://www.dave-cushman.net/bee/sba_july07.html) that use "staff and distaff", as well as [someone else remembering an elderly relative using it](http://talk.newagtalk.com/forums/thread-view.asp?tid=84555&mid=605279#M605279).

Comment: My immediate thought was "datstaff".

Answer (score -1):

During the Middle Ages, spinning and weaving flax and wool were cottage industries.  The typical division of labor was that the women spun while the men knit.  So, I suppose you would put the distaff and knotting pins as a connected pair.

Answer (score -2):

How about simply the word *masculine*?

**EDIT:**

This wasn't random, as I believe it clearly relates to the question: if *distaff* is taken to mean "the female equivalent of something typically male", then the desired antonym should mean "the male equivalent of something typically female", no? Honestly, 'male' is the word I would have suggested, but that's already been suggested and rejected, so I chose a related word which had yet to be suggested.

Judging by MετάEd's comment, it needs to also (or perhaps instead) express 'paternal', which changes the desired definition to be something like "the paternal equivalent of something typically female". To me, however, 'paternal' doesn't necessarily imply 'male', as it brings to table the issue of gender roles, which is, I believe, outside the scope of the question.

*Distaff*, being used as a modifier in phrases such as "marriage is still the passport to distaff power", would be taken to mean "of or concerning women"<sup>[1](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/distaff)</sup>. Having learned this, and using 'masculine' to mean "having qualities traditionally associated with men; manly; virile," I can see that the word doesn't quite encompass what we need for either this definition or the OP's: *masculine* encompasses a set of characteristics typically attributed to men, and is, to a great extent, subjective; it is not a word that is directly tied to something that is *male* or a *male equivalent*.

Having now considered the matter further, I would suggest something which builds on the root *andro-*, the Greek root for 'man' or 'male'. Also, perhaps, the word should end with *-al*, from the Latin suffix meaning 'of or pertaining to'.

Comment: Why *masculine*? How about justifying your answer and not tossing suggestions randomly. :)

Comment: *Masculine* is an adjective which sometimes is applied to women (it can be uncomplimentary to do so). It means "manlike", not "male" or "paternal".

Comment: You can always edit and improve your answer. (P.S I didn't downvote but "masculine" is not good enough)